# clone() method in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, clone

### Working with clone() in hashmap:

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(1, "Raj");
map.put(3, "Kumar");
map.put(2, "Ram");

HashMap map1 = (HashMap) map.clone();

map1.put(7, "Kavin");

System.out.println("Map1: "+map1);
System.out.println("Map: "+map);
```

This will give the output as,

**Map1: {1=Raj, 2=Ram, 3=Kumar, 7=Kavin}

Map: {1=Raj, 2=Ram, 3=Kumar}**

But if i try to run in **jdk8**, it throws compilation error.

**Note: HelloWorld.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.          
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.**

### **Program 2:**

```
  HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("Java", 8);
    map.put("Csharp", 5);
    Map<String, Integer> mapClone = (Map<String, Integer>) 
            Collections.checkedMap((Map<String, Integer>)map.clone(),  String.class, Integer.class);
```

But if i try to run in **jdk8**, it throws compilation error.

**Note: HelloWorld.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.          
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.**

why??...

Comment: I see no compilation **error**.

Comment: These are compiler *warnings*. Your program has compiled succesfully.

Comment: It is only a warning.

Comment: Plus, the compiler gave you the exact option to use to get an answer to your *why* question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: HelloWorld.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>
> Note:Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

These are just warnings not `Compilation Error`

> These warning simply means  that the compiler can't check that you're
>   using the collection in a type-safe way, using generics.

Comment: Thank you... But, What is this warning really mean??

Comment: Compile your code with -Xlint flag you will get detailed explanation

Comment: Sorry. How to compile like that.? what is -Xlint flag?? I dont have any knowledge about it... please help me..

Comment: `javac -Xlint YourJavaProgram.java` , Try this command in your `terminal/cmd`

Comment: -X is a standard prefix for all kinds of "extended options" in Java commands. `lint` is a standard term for generating detailed warnings about suspicious stuff in your code. Read the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) entry on it.